# Can't Import Guava's MoreAsserts in Eclipse

Tags: guava

I recently added Google Guava as a library to my Eclipse project (I downloaded the 'guava-16.0.jar' from http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/ and added it as an external jar library to my Eclipse project).

Eclipse seems to be able to "see"/use the library (I have successfully made imports to packages like com.google.common.collect).  Now I want to use the [MoreAsserts](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/src/com/google/common/testing/MoreAsserts.java?r=697576a2b9c0a9321f7dc2a027e1e530215ee953) class in some of my JUnit tests, but when I type in the import:

```
import com.google.common.testing.MoreAsserts;
```

Eclipse gives a red flag saying that "The import com.google.common.testing could not be resolved".  It doesn't seem to see the package at all.

[EDIT: I think this might be because MoreAsserts is in Beta version (tagged as @Beta), and so I probably shouldn't use it anyway]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The testing package is not distributed in the Guava release. I think it is meant for the Guava tests themselves, not for the general public.

It's not mentioned in the [Javadocs](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/index.html) either.

Answer (score 11):

Contrary to some of the responses here, `com.google.common.testing` is available for public use. It's just that it's hidden away in a separate [`guava-testlib`](http://search.maven.org/#browse%7C319062948) artifact at Maven Central.

That said, you won't find `MoreAsserts` there. It was removed a few years ago. (The source link you gave points to an old version of Guava. I'm kind of curious where you got the link.)

*That* said, the reason that `MoreAsserts` was deleted is that it has been replaced by a more comprehensive `equals()` and `hashCode()` tester: [`EqualsTester`](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/guava-testlib/src/com/google/common/testing/EqualsTester.java). `EqualsTester` *is* in the current version of `guava-testlib`.

It's true that the class is `@Beta`, but that's probably OK for tests. (And practically speaking, `EqualsTester` is unlikely to change significantly.)

> [APIs marked with the @Beta annotation at the class or method level
>   are subject to change. They can be modified in any way, or even
>   removed, in any major release. If your code is a library itself (i.e.
>   it is used on the CLASSPATH of users outside your own control), you
>   should not use beta APIs.](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)

Comment: I tend to disagree. If it was meant for public use, it would have been documented (or at least mentioned) on the guava website, not "hidden away" in Maven Central where no one can find it.

Comment: Not widely publicised but fantastically useful. I wrote a small introduction to building test suites: http://www.joekearney.co.uk/work/guava-testlib-example.html

Comment: MoreAsserts is still part of Android SDK: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/MoreAsserts.html

Answer (score -2):

If you have downloaded guava from your link, the jar does not contain the package

```
import com.google.common.testing
```

That's why you couldn't use the class MoreAsserts.

If you want to know which classes are in a jar, you can:

1) Open the file, is just a compressed file. Then you can see what packages (folders) and classes are inside the jar

2) With eclipse, in the import line, you can navigate typing `import com.` and waiting some secs (or pressing Ctrl+space)

Answer (score -2):

The `MoreAsserts` is not included in the guava-16.0.jar. If you need the functionality from the class, just copy the class from their GIT repository - there is only one public method anyway.